# Anyone else having trouble w/ JSONKit and the delegate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, categories, jsonkit

I'm experiencing some problems with JSONKit. I've got an object A which imports another class which imports JSONKit.h. In A I try to parse an `NSArray` containing some custom objects which for I implemented a custom formatter class to set as the delegate when calling `-JSONStringWithOptions:serializeUnsupportedClassesUsingDelegate:selector:error:`. Xcode does autocomplete this method perfectly. When running the code my app crashes and tells me

`-[_PFArray JSONStringWithOptions:serializeUnsupportedClassesUsingDelegate:selector:error:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance

Somehow `JSONKit`'s `NSArray` category does not seem to work. I'm sure I'm just making a stupid mistake and I'm missing just a little piece.

Thanks guys
–f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Turns out, removing and re-adding `JSONKit` fixes the issue…

–f